# jQuery select elements loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery

The following code runs a simple auto-suggest task, this itself is working fine. The problem is that it does not run when the div with class "ausu-suggest" was brought on to the page via AJAX.

Inside the div is a form field. When you start typing in the form field, the autosuggest starts.

I know I should probably use the live() function but I'm unsure of the syntax since this isn't tied to a particular event. ie, the function below doesn't need a change() or onKeyUp() even to run.

```
$.fn.autosugguest({
             className: 'ausu-suggest',
             methodType: 'POST',
             dataFile: "<?=site_url('survey/search_city')?>",
             minChars: 3,   
             rtnIDs: true,
        });
```

EDIT: The actual plugin code is here http://discussion.oslund.ca/2011/01/a-simple-jquery-ajax-autosuggest-plugin/

Comment: I think we need to see the actual plugin code in action.

Comment: The snippet above is all that's needed, wrapped in a $(document).ready().

Comment: With all the dovuted respect, but how should I suppose to know the meaning of those bytes without the plugin code? That code you linked is extending the jQuery base functionalities adding a custom plugin. Sorry but I don't know what kind of plugin it is.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript code is applied at a moment in time. It's only going to apply to what's on the page right now, and it won't automatically rerun itself later just because the DOM changed. You're responsible for that.

In your success function for your AJAX you simply need to reapply the autosuggest plugin to the new content after it's loaded into the DOM.

(As a side note, jQuery has a `live` function that can be used to automatically apply event handlers to new elements as they pop up in the DOM, but jQuery does this by attaching a handler to an ancestor element that checks for DOM changes and then reloads the event handler. It's not *technically* automatic.)

**EDIT:** (example)

```
$.fn.autosugguest({
         className: 'ausu-suggest',
         methodType: 'POST',
         dataFile: "<?=site_url('survey/search_city')?>",
         minChars: 3,   
         rtnIDs: true,
    });

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain.com/ajax',
    success: function (data) {
        // Write new input to DOM

        $.fn.autosugguest({
            className: 'ausu-suggest',
            methodType: 'POST',
            dataFile: "<?=site_url('survey/search_city')?>",
            minChars: 3,   
            rtnIDs: true,
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: How would you "reapply" the plugin?

Comment: You rerun the code you used in the first place. The only potential problem here is whether or not the plugin is smart enough to detect it's already been ran on an element. For example, if you had one autosuggest input on the page already, ran the plugin on it onload, then add a new input and run the plugin again to hit that one, will it apply another version of itself to the first? A well designed plugin won't, but even if it does, you can get around that by using a different class for the dynamically loaded one, and matching that new class instead of the original when you run the plugin code.